# Pivot Table in Tabular Report Format presented in a vertical manner

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

When I am analyzing data/information, I usually use pivot function of Excel to have a better view of the voluminous data that I have. I use the **Tabular Format** as the report layout and just click on fields that are relevant for my analysis.

However, the tabular format shows/arranges the fields in a **horizontal manner**. Is there any way to present them in a **vertical manner**?

Let me show you an example:

When you select the following fields in field list (see screenshot below), the following will be the result:

[image: Pivot Field Selection and Pivot Results]

I wanted to present the fields in vertical manner, like this one:

[image: Desired Pivot Result]

How is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: What would that look like? Mock up an example manually and post a screenshot

Comment: hi teylyn, I had updated my post.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-Field-List-to-arrange-fields-in-a-PivotTable-43980e05-a585-4fcd-bd91-80160adfebec), did you followed the steps there and still couldn't achieve what you need?

Comment: Hi Mate. I think this would suffice. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've added more than one fields to the "Values" part of the pivot table, a field called "Values" is automatically added to "Columns", just move this field to "Rows".

[image]

Comment: Nice. +1 I removed my false claim. I think your solution is what the OP may be after. I'll leave my post up to illustrate the unpivot effect.

Answer (score 0):

When you drag fields into the rows well of the pivot table panel, you are creating a hierarchy.

Maybe you first need to unpivot your source data, so it does not have columns for a, b, c, etc, but these are values in a categorical column. So instead of source data and pivot like this:

[image]

... unpivot the source data to look like the following table. Then you can pivot like below.

[image]

Comment: " The order that you describe is not possible with the pivot source arranged like that" - it is possible, see my answer.

Comment: seems a little bit complicated to me. Thanks anyway.